# crittercism - Not possible see my console crash log in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, crittercism

How can I do to see the log of the crash in Xcode?, because when I have active the crittercism, with debugger mode, can not see the console log, always if I want to use xcode debugger, I need to disable crittercism and I think that is wrong.

Crittercism is right, it sends the report to the web service when open the app, but if I have the device connect to xcode, I can not see in the reports of the crash and crittercism does not send it to the web it.

I do not know if something is missing, exist something like a line that I need to add for this start to work ?

Comment: I've never used Crittercism, but it sounds to me like what you are doing is _right_ - you do not enable it during _development_ but you enable it in the _shipping_ version of the app.

Comment: I use Crashlytics but only in Release mode.  That's done by testing the `$CONFIGURATION` variable when "running" crashlytics (which uploads the `.dsym` files to their site).  In code I have custom logging code and that decides to either log using `NSLog()` (Debug) or using `CLSNSLog()` (Crashlytics logging that accompanies any crash logs).  Of course none of this might be possible with Crittercism (I've never used it).

Answer (score 0):

I've used Crittercism extensively for iOS and Android.
You should be able to see your Crash Logs in both Xcode as well as 
within the Crittercism platform when your device is connected to Xcode.

Also, be sure you've configured your app for automatic symbolication.
see this [article](http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/Uploading-dSYMs-to-Crittercism-automatically/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this do not work for me, I do not know what is missing, this is my script, may be something is wrong here, APP_ID="xasdasdasasdasd"
API_KEY="asdasdasdasdasdasdasd"
source "${SRCROOT}"/CrittercismSDK/dsym_upload.sh
SHOW_CONSOLE=1
SIM_DSYM_UPLOAD=1

Comment: This may be obvious but is your APP_ID and API_Key the actual values provided by Crittercism?

Comment: No, is only a APP_ID and API_KEY example, because Crittercism work, it send report to the server, but if I want to do debug, I have to disable line of appDelegate, and it is so ugly and wrong.

Comment: Or exist something to know if app is running from xcode ?

Comment: Try adding the actual APP_ID and API_KEY provided. This is a requirement to communicate with the platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried and does not work :/, is like a something line missing